# Prove that $S = \{A \in GL_n(K) | AJA^t = J\}$ is a subgroup of $GL_n(K)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, discrete-mathematics, field-theory

Given a field $K$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $J \in K^{n \times n}$, show that:

$$
S = \{A \in GL_n(K) | AJA^t = J\}
$$
is a subgroup of $GL_n(K)$.

To show that S is a subgroup, we must show:

It must include the neutral element: $e \in S$

For $a,b \in S$, $S$ must include: $a \cdot b^{-1} \in S$.

1.) Showing that $e \in S$:

Since $J$ is an element over the field $K$, the multiplication has a neutral element. Therefore we choose $J = E_n$. The neutral element must also be part of the linear group over $K$, therefore if we choose $A = E_n$, we can conclude that the neutral element is in $S$.

2.)
Given an $a := AJA^t = J , b := BIB^t = I$ we will show that $a \cdot b^{-1}$ will also be in $S$. The inverse of $b$ is defined as: $b^{-1} = (B^t)^{-1}I^{-1}B^{-1}$. Therefore:
$$
AJA^t(B^t)^{-1}I^{-1}B^{-1} = JI^{-1}
$$
But I am not sure how to proceed ...

Comment: In (2) you need to show that if $AJA^t=B^JB^t=J$ then $CJC^t=J$ where $C=AB^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following method shows that $S$ is the kernel of a homomorphism defined on $GL_{n}(K)$.  The kernel of a homomorphism is always a normal subgroup.

Regard $K^{n \times n}$ as a vector space (of dimension $n^2$) over $K$.

For each $A \in GL_{n}(K)$, we define a linear transformation $\phi[A]$ on the vector space $K^{n \times n}$ as follows:
$$
\phi[A] J = A J A^{t}.
$$
Furthermore, $\phi[A]$ is invertible, and
$$
\phi[B] \phi[A] = \phi[BA].
$$
Therefore, $\phi$ is a homomorphism from group $GL_{n}(K)$ to the group of the invertible linear transformations on $K^n$.

And $S$ is the kernel of that homomorphism, hence is a subgroup of $GL_{n}(K)$, and even a normal subgroup.